# Подсветка текущей строки в JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, gui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется программа, где 1 - JPanel, 2 - JTextPane. Надо реализовать выделение строки, в которой в данный момент установлена каретка. Помогите найти пример реализации, ну или подтолкните куда думать, пожалуйста)

Comment: Обратите внимание на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405550/highlight-current-row-in-jtextpane. Возможно вы имели ввиду именно это

Comment: Действительно, по ссылке есть ответ. Довольно очевидный кстати, и подтолкнувший на мысль к более хорошей реализации не только этого вопроса. Мне стыдно) Спасибо.